# PayPal integration in Laravel site

Tags: laravel, paypal, frontend

I need to implement PayPal payment in my Laravel site. I was going for the server side integration, in order to save all the data, transactions and know what they actually bought. But turns out that [the older] server-side integration method [that I was looking at] is archived, and not really the preferred method anymore. Instead, they suggest using the smart buttons, with front end integration only.

Questions:

- Is front end only safe? what prevents the user from messing with the JavaScript and editing the sum with whatever they want?
- How do I know what they ordered if it is all front end?
- What would I have to do if the payed sum does not correspond to the articles in the cart?
- What should I be aware of with this system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart Payment Buttons can be used with or without a server-side component.

Here is the front-end pattern that communicates with a server-side integration: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Notice the fetches to two '/demo/...' placeholder endpoints, which need to be replaced with actual routes of yours.  The first should create a v2/order via API and return the orderID.  The second should capture that order after the payer approves it via Smart Payment Buttons.

---

The answers to your questions re: a serverless (client-side only) pattern are:

- Nothing
- Only what you program the JavaScript to tell you and which it actually successfully tells you, or what you read via email or in your PayPal account or app notifications
- Refund the transaction
- It's for people who don't want to do the work of implementing server-side routes and API calls.